# Getting full path from QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have 2 listwidgets, lets call them listwidgetinput and listwidgetoutput. I have alot of files(only file name) on listwidgetinput. And i trim the file name before adding it to listwidgetinput like this `it.fileName()`. and i transfer the selected files to listdigetoutput like:

```js
QList <QListWidgetItem*> items=ui->listWidgetinput->selectedItems();
for(int j=0;j<items.count();j++)
{
list= items.at(j)->text();
ui->listWidgetOutput->insertItem(j,list);
```

After i transfer the file can i get the path for all the files?. If Yes, how?

edit: code where whole path is available.

```js
QString Dir, Type;
QStringList Files;
Qlistwidget wid

if (index==0)
  {
    Dir.append(C:\desktop....);
    type.append(".txt")
    wid = ui->listwidgetinput_txt;
    }
if (index ==1)
  {
    Dir.append(C:\desktop....);
    type.append(".doc")
    wid = ui->listwidgetinput_doc
    }
QDirIterator it(Dir, QStringList() << Type, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        
        Files.append(it.fileName());
      }
wid->additems(Files);
```

Comment: Please add a bit more code... in particular the piece of code where you still have the full path available.

Comment: Added like u asked. @hyde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QListWidgetItem::setData()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData) to pass additional "invisible" properties like the full path when creating the item:

```
auto item = new QListWidgetItem;
item->setText(fileInfo.fileName());
item->setData(Qt::UserRole, fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
...
```

Later you can retrieve it via [QListWidgetItem::data()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#data):

```
const auto fullPath = item->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
```

Comment: Why can't you change the code around `wid->additems(Files);`? This being a pure UI thing, what does the backend have to do with it?

Comment: i gave this a try, sorry i am just a beginner. so is this how you asked me to do it? `QDirIterator it(myDir, QStringList() << myType, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);<br/>  auto item = new QListWidgetItem; <br/> while (it.hasNext()){ <br/> it.next();<br/> item->setText(it.fileName()); <br/> item->setData(Qt::UserRole, it.filePath()); <br/> myWidget->addItems(item);`

Comment: You need to create the item inside the loop (one item in each iteration) and use addItem, not addItems. But apart from that, yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks, im still stuck at path extraction part. why do i have to use const auto ?

Comment: You don’t have to use auto, you can also just type out QString if that’s more to your liking. (or you can’t use C++11).